# Error message on MCTDH block relaxation calculation

Tags: mctdh

I am running a MCTDH block relaxation for vibronic models and got the following error message:

ERROR in subroutine rdavstep:
Illegal integration order

My input file is as follow:

```
RUN-SECTION
title = block improved water relaxation
name = h2o_ev
relaxation=0,olsen precon=50 orben
tout = 5.0 tfinal = 30.00
rlxunit=eV, 0.0
psi=double
end-run-section

OPERATOR-SECTION
opname = h2o_ev
end-operator-section

SPF-BASIS-SECTION
packet=1000, single-set
      v01      =  35
      v02      =  35
      v03      =  35
end-spf-basis-section

PRIMITIVE-BASIS-SECTION
    v01    HO     35   0.0   1.0   1.0
    v02    HO     35   0.0   1.0   1.0
    v03    HO     35   0.0   1.0   1.0
    el     el     3
end-primitive-basis-section

INTEGRATOR-SECTION
CMF/varphi = 0.5, 1.0d-08
RK8/spf = 1.0d-8, 0.1
rrDAV = 1000, 1.0d-11
end-integrator-section

INIT_WF-SECTION
build
   init_state=2
-----------------------------------------------------------
#  mode   type  center  moment.  freq.    mass
-----------------------------------------------------------
    v01    HO     0.0    0.0      1.0     1.0
    v02    HO     0.0    0.0      1.0     1.0
    v03    HO     0.0    0.0      1.0     1.0
-----------------------------------------------------------
end-build
autoblock
end-init_wf-section

end-input
```

The goal of this calculation is to obtain energy eigenvalues of the low lying eigenstates of this vibronic model. Anyone knows the origin of this error?

Comment: The error message suggests that something is wrong with the integrator. Can you run the same calculation, but change RK8 to a different integrator?

Comment: +1 but why are you using `RK8`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I am now try to run calculation using RK5 integrator. Since this calculation is for the benchmark purpose, I want to minimize the truncation error.

Comment: Did it work with RK5 or a different integrator?